# HTML input box which displays its output next to it

Tags: input, output

So i was wondering how to have an input box from which a person can write html into as practice and then its output is next to it. For example say i wrote < p > < strong > Hello World < /strong > < / p >     in the input box. The output would be

**Hello World**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a local host or server for PHP, you could try with angular.js ? 
something like this :

---

html:

```
 <body ng-app="nameapp" ng-controller="myController">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Header of your page</h1>

            <div class="center">
                <label for="name">Tell me, what is your name?</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="myName"/>
                <p ng-if="myName">Hello {{myName}}, order some drinks!</p>
            </div>
```

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('nameapp', []);

        app.controller('myController', function($scope){
            console.log('hi there!', $scope);

          $scope.myName = '';


 });
```